# binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I am writing a template class function comparing std::strings.  std::string is the template parameter. My problem is that I can't compare two const string with "==" operator, then I think I create two non-const temporary string variables to performe the comparation, but it still can't compile. Don't know why.

class VGraph is instanced as `VGraph<std::string, std::string> myGraph;`

```
template <typename V, typename E>
size_t VGraph<V, E>::find(const V& vert)
{
    V temp = vert; // (1)
    for (size_t i=0; i<graph.size(); i++)
    {
        V noneConst = graph[i].getVertex(); // (2)
        if (temp==noneConst)// I think broblem is here, and tried to fix using (1)(2)
            return i;
    }
    return graph.size();
}
```

Prototype of related function

```
template <typename V, typename E>
const V& VVertex<V, E>::getVertex();
```

Comment: what is V in the instantiation you use?

Comment: You can compare two const strings or two const references to a string perfectly fine, your problem must lie somwhere else.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: I assume that the error message is `binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`. Otherwise the title of this question would be very counterintuitive.

Comment: Comparing two const std::strings is fine.  Your problem is elsewhere.  Does your code (where you instantiate the template) #include <string>  ?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Doesn't the error message claim that the left hand operand is a `std::string`?

Comment: @PlasmaHH The template class is instanced as VGraph<std::string, std::string> myGraph. V should be a std::string here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably forgot an explicit:

```
#include <string>
```

The `std::string` class is defined by a another header you included, but not the operator `==`.

Comment: This is a template class. do I need to include the instance class header file? I think I will need to include string in client code, right?

Comment: Yeah man, you are right. client code forgot to include <string>. It's weird that it passed the compilation when the class instance is declared using VGraph<string, string> without including <string> header, that made me ignored the issue.